# Looping folder names to a variable using Batch?

Tags: variables, loops, batch-file, directory

I'm wanting to change the icon of every sub folder in a particular directory, can I do this by means of a loop similar to the %%~nxf used for files (I’m after folders not files)

```
attrib -h -r C:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\Customisations\AO2\EXE\desktop.ini 
echo [.ShellClassInfo] >C:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\Customisations\AO2\EXE\desktop.ini 
echo IconFile= C:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\Customisations\AO2\ICO\FolderIcon.ico >>C:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\Customisations\AO2\EXE\desktop.ini 
echo InfoTip=EXE file location... >>C:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\Customisations\AO2\EXE\desktop.ini
echo IconIndex=0 >>C:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\Customisations\AO2\EXE\desktop.ini 
attrib +h +r C:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\Customisations\AO2\EXE\desktop.ini 
attrib +r C:\ICT\AutoCAD_2010\Customisations\AO2\EXE
```

Of cause do this a couple of hundred times in a batch and well you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may process folders (not files) with /D switch of for command:

```
for /D %%a in (*) do echo Folder: %%a
```

You may also combine /R with /D to process every subfolder beneath the given path. For further details, type: `for /?`